# What is the default servlet for JBoss AS 7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss7.x

I recently converted non-javaEE project to JavaEE using Netbeans and Glassfish. But now I must use JBoss server and the old Glassfish servlet I used for web services was `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`.

But on the new JBoss project I got the following error:

> Attribute servlet-class references to non-existent class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

What is the default servlet for JBoss AS 7?

Comment: Jersey is a non-standard component. Your application will not be portable if you don't stick with standard components (i.e. ones beginning `javax.*`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to post stupid threads. Of course `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` will work.